# Machine Learning resources

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but is there any online source that provides a complete in-depth explanation of Machine Learning algorithms, **all at one place**, but not too complicated for a beginner to understand?

Every source I refer to either covers the topics superficially or focuses on only one aspect of the algorithm which makes me waste a big chunk of my study time going through different websites & videos looking for the same.

Answer (score 2):

How to Learn Data Science For Free

Python
Corey Schafer
https://www.youtube.com/user/schafer5
Sentdex
https://www.youtube.com/user/sentdex
Machine Learning with Maths, Statistics and Linear Algebra
Andrew NG applied AI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPLop4L2eGk&list=PLLssT5z_DsK-h9vYZkQkYNWcItqhlRJLN
Krish Naik
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqRsD3gqeCo&list=PLZoTAELRMXVOnN_g96ayzXX5i7RRO0QhL

Sentdex
https://www.youtube.com/user/sentdex

Statquest with Josh Starmer
https://www.youtube.com/user/joshstarmer

Natural Language Processing
Krish
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZVf1jnEKGI&list=PLZoTAELRMXVMdJ5sqbCK2LiM0HhQVWNzm
Sentdex
https://www.youtube.com/user/sentdex

Deep Learning
Andrew Ng
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CS4cs9xVecg&list=PLkDaE6sCZn6Ec-XTbcX1uRg2_u4xOEky0
Krish Naik
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKSZHN7jftI&list=PLZoTAELRMXVPGU70ZGsckrMdr0FteeRUi

Data Science Projects
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Txi0nHIe0o&list=PLZoTAELRMXVNUcr7osiU7CCm8hcaqSzGw

Blogs that are freely Available
https://towardsdatascience.com/
https://medium.com/topic/machine-learning

Feature Engineering Playlist
https://github.com/aikho/awesome-feature-engineering

Feature Selection Playlist
https://github.com/anujdutt9/Feature-Selection-for-Machine-Learning

Krish Naik Featured Engineering:
https://github.com/krishnaik06/Complete-Feature-Engineering
https://github.com/krishnaik06/Feature-Engineering

Book (Python For Finance)
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-on-Python-for-Finance

Kaggle Solution
http://ndres.me/kaggle-past-solutions/

How to Learn Data Science For Free.docx
Ref : https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/113420

For more advanced resources visit [this link](https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/129578)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html). It is a python library which implements many ML algorithms and describes how they work to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

This is excellent, for beginners, intermediate level users, and experts too!

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/user_guide.html

Answer (score 1):

The following are 2 handy reference books on ML and Deep Learning. There should be some free pdf versions that you can download on the web.

1. Introduction to Machine Learning with Python by Andreas C. Müller and Sarah Guido
   https://pdfroom.com/books/introduction-to-machine-learning-with-python-a-guide-for-data-scientists/qjb5q6ykdxQ
2. Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras & TensorFlow by Aurélien Géron

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at „[Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www.statlearning.com/)“. This book is for beginners but written by top academics. It comes with R „labs“ (also Python version available), so that you can try things out and learn R if you don‘t do it already.

In case you want to dig deeper into one or another topic, you may refer to „Elements of Statistical Learning“ which is like the „grown-up“ counterpart to ISL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for practical python examples, check out this [website with multiple programming examples for beginners](https://databasecamp.de/en/homepage).